# Using AngularJs in order to retrieve a header from the response and set it on all requests

Tags: angularjs, csrf

I am trying to use **Angularjs** in order to retrieve the **csrf token** from one of the response's header and set it on all requests.

I have managed to read it from the response using a response interceptor as follows:

```
 .factory('csrfResponseInterceptor', [function () {
        return{
            response: function(response){
                console.log(response.headers('X-CSRF-TOKEN'));
                return response;
            }
        }
    }])
```

but I am not sure how to set it on all requests afterwards.

Somehow I would need to set it using the `$httpProvider` service as follows:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = response.headers('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
```

I haven't managed to inject the `$httpProvider` into the interceptor though.

Can someone please provide advice on a best practice?

**edit**: This is how I register my interceptors:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpResponseInterceptor', 'csrfResponseInterceptor');
    }])
```

Comment: Can you post the code of how you register this interceptor `csrfResponseInterceptor`?

Comment: @dfsq: I have edited my post as requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it like this in config function:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
            response: function(response) {
                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = response.headers('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
                return response;
            }
        }    
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same interceptor to intercept any request generating from your application and inject the token into it. For example:

```
.factory('csrfResponseInterceptor', [function () {
        var token = null;

        return{
            request: function(config){
                if(token){
                   config.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token;
                }
                return config;
            },
            response: function(response){
                token = response.headers('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
                return response;
            }
        }
    }])
```