# Sockjs fallback with Spring Security CSRF enable

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf, sockjs

My project use Spring Security + Spring MVC and deals with websocket (over stomp+sockjs). 
When I test the sockjs fallback the XHR request return 403.
If I turn off csrf on the security context it's OK.
If I override the sockjs AbstractXHRObject constructor like this : it's ok :

```
function AbstractXHRObject(method, url, payload, opts) {
  debug(method, url);
  var self = this;
  EventEmitter.call(this);

  // HACK : add csrf headers
  opts["headers"][csrfHeader] = csrfToken;

  setTimeout(function () {
    self._start(method, url, payload, opts);
  }, 0);
}
```

*Off course I have to check if opts is not null...*

My question is : **What is the way to add headers on the XHR fallback object of SockJS** ?

Thanks

Comment: no idea about sockjs in case of angularjs you can add intercept and add headers like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332717/using-angularjs-in-order-to-retrieve-a-header-from-the-response-and-set-it-on-al

Answer (score 1):

Finally I disable CSRF for sockjs URL in my security context.

```
 <security:csrf request-matcher-ref="csrfMatcher" />
```

and the matcher :

```
public class CsrfSecurityRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {

    private Pattern                 allowedMethods      = Pattern.compile("^(GET|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS)$");
    private AntPathRequestMatcher   unprotectedMatcher  = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/ws/**/xhr_send**");

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (allowedMethods.matcher(request.getMethod()).matches()) {
            return false;
        }

        return !unprotectedMatcher.matches(request);
    }
}
```

NOTE : It follow http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2014/04/customizing-csrf-protection-in-spring-security/